# Generalized variance in PCA

Tags: variance, pca, covariance-matrix

This generalized variance is a term that I have trouble understanding, simply because I can't find much on it on the internet,.i.e. which is the formula and some of its advantages and/or disadvantages? I came across this question while reading multivariate statistics and then in PCA, where I have stumbled upon the following two problems.

1. Suppose that two variables have total variance equal to 10. And generalized variance equal to 9. Both variables have equal variances. Find the correlation of the two variables.
2. Suppose that a Princepal Component(PC) explains the 90% of the total variance. One variable has variance equal to 10. Find the correlation between that variable and the PC.

Comment: Did your source (where you read these two problems) give any definition of "generalized variance"? As far as I know, it is not a standard term.

Comment: Well unfortunately it doesnt say anything more than the fact that it is the determinant of the covariance matrix. Using that information I managed to solve the first question, yet not sure if correct. Or how it is applied in the PCA.